# How to set the class of a UIButton set programatically

Tags: swift, uibutton

How to set the class of a UIButton set programatically.

The first line was created using interface builder and the other lines are to create the button programatically. The other file contains the drawing code.

One

```
@IBOutlet var eddieButton: DrawButton!
```

Two

```
let newDocButton = UIButton()
newDocButton.setTitle("New", forState: .Normal)
newDocButton.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
newDocButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.darkGrayColor(), forState: .Normal)
newDocButton.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 40, 40)


newDocButton.addTarget(self, action: "createNewDoc:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
self.effectBG.addSubview(newDocButton)
```

Comment: So... What's the problem that you're seeing? You are setting the class of the button programmatically in "Two" - you've created a UIButton.

Comment: Did you try `let newDocButton = DrawButton()` ?

Answer (score 0):

This works.

`let button = ButtonDrawing.buttonWithType(.Custom) as UIButton`